# Memory leak when using threads in ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have a script that should ping hosts in separate threads. Separate threads are used for separate specific hosts pinging, because some pings sometimes takes longer than others. And if we will wait some one ping - others timeouts gets bigger than real.

That's code create a separate thread for each host. I just copy-pasted it from some example. I'am not sure that this code correct. Also I has memory leaks.

```
threads = []

config.each do |array_item|
  host = array_item[0]
  packet_size = array_item[1]
  threads << Thread.new do                                                                                    
    puts "\nCreating a thread for host:#{host} value:#{packet_size}"
    ping(host, packet_size)
  end
end
threads.each(&:join)
```

Also I run into heap analyzing, but cannot understand what's wrong. I just suppose that threads are not terminates.

```
Analyzing Heap (Generation: 10)
-------------------------------

allocated by memory (4717121) (in bytes)
==============================
  3150072  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:81
  1050024  ./pinger.rb:166
```

`./pinger.rb:166` - is points to `threads << Thread.new do`

Do I need to control threads allocation and some sort of threads closing controls ?

Comment: The line `threads << Thread.new do` initializes a thread and stores it in a variable. Why are you surprised that this step allocates memory? Why do you think there is a memory leak in your code? Why do you think something is wrong? Is there an error?

Comment: Memory leak usually means you has increasing amount of memory taken over time. Can post here how much memory was taken after 1 minute of script working, and, let's say, after 5 minutes? Is there any difference?

PS. The code sample looks okay to me...

Comment: Year, of course. Script starts at 18 Mb memory allocation, grows every few seconds, grows up to 5 gigabytes in a couple of days.

Comment: I can assume that the matter is inside the function ping(host, packet_size). It is strange that the objects created inside the thread, after the end of thread continue to take memory. Maybe it's not. I dont know. Is it possible to either guarantee (implement) the re-creation of threads every time for each function call? To be sure that objects generated in the thread are deleted (if I understand correctly what I'm doing). As far as I understand, the thread is a separate process. The completion of the process must be accompanied by the release of memory. But I do not know how to implement this.

Comment: What does `ping(host, packet_size)` do? If that method does not return for some reason that could be the source of the leak.

Comment: Most likely I realized that the problem is inside this function. Thanks to everyone.